# Styling elements based on parent

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm attempting to style just the first two  elements of this particular table:

```
<table class="myTable">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>some stuff</td>   <--- needs style
           <td>some stuff</td>   <--- needs style
           <td>some stuff</td>
           <td>some stuff</td>
           <td>some stuff</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Multiple tables exist on my HTML page so I don't believe I want to use first-child or nth-child selectors. What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add an id or add a class to the table cells.. if you cant you are going to have to target it using nth-child or jquery/javascript

Comment: Why don't you add an ID to that `particular table`? And then use `nth-child`.

Comment: why not? nth-child works just fine with multiple tables, http://jsfiddle.net/n5eth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if that class is unique to the table in question, `nth-child` is the way to go:

```
.myTable tr:first-child td:nth-child(1), 
.myTable tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

...assuming you only want to style the first two columns in the table's first row. Otherwise, for all rows:

```
.myTable td:nth-child(1), 
.myTable td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/eogcb

Answer (score 0):

Put an Id on the table and then access selectors via id

OR

if that's not possible try this

```
$('.myTable td:lt(3)').addClass('yourClass');
```

PS:Please remember that n-the child is 1 based and not 0 based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use nth-child selectors for a specific class or even ID which is more strict. What makes you think that you can't use them in this case?